# Installing GCC 5.2.0 in RHEL 8.8

Tags: rhel8, gcc

I'm trying to install GCC 5.2.0 in my RHEL 8.8 server as it requires by a tool that I'm using. However, I'm getting an error when running the `make` command. Below are the commands I used including the error i'm getting:

```
tar -xvf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.2.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir gcc-build-5.2.0
cd gcc-build-5.2.0
$PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable-packages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
strace make -j 4

Error:
make[3]: *** [build/gensupport.o] Error 1
rm gcc.pod
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-build'
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 2}], 0, NULL) = 1597031
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1597031, si_uid=0, si_status=2, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1597031
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0
read(7, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2997
read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(7)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/make.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "make: ", 6make: )                   = 6
write(2, "*** [all] Error 2", 17*** [all] Error 2)       = 17
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT TERM XCPU XFSZ], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "+", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "+", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "+", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
chdir("/root/gcc-build")                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

I already installed the "Developer Tools" and "gcc-c++" but I'm still getting this error and stuck on this. Hopefully someone can help debug it.

Comment: Why are you running make with strace? Just run `make` on its own and let us see the errors without the bumf. It also looks like you have cut out the first and most important error.